# Populating Date Column in Sheets from a Cell with manually-entered Month

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm creating a monthly form in Google Sheets.

In one cell the month is entered manually, eq. December 2022.

I want to dynamically populate a column of dates which references the month, so the column will update each time a new month is entered.

12/1/22
12/2/22
12/3/22
etc.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you enter the month/year as a date (the first day of the month you desire, you can then work with it:
[image]

As in my example sheet, if you have the desired month in B2 and you want to start in A2 the dates, you can use this arrayformula:

> =arrayformula(if(row(A2:A32)-1>day(EOMONTH($B$1,0)),"",date(year($B$1),month($B$1),row(A2:A32)-1)))

Note that "-1" is because we're starting in row 2, if you need to start in row 1 delete it, and if you need to start below, change "-1" with "-2" or "-3", etc...

Here's the sheet with it ;) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W5j6cl9YR_F5tDYC2koAtEUmRloWqxEjce8Ojfp_8sI/edit#gid=0

[image]

Comment: Thanks! A bit complicated for me, but I learned a lot. Here's another solution I found:

=SEQUENCE(EOMONTH(D1;0)-D1+1;1;D1)

Comment: Great! There's always more than one solution with different tools and logics! Thanks for sharing yours too!